# replace document with AJAX results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that submits to a script which can take a long time to execute (~30-60 seconds, give or take).  I would like to have a spinner that shows the results are processing while the user waits.  Normally, I would stick the spinner in the processing script and be done with it, but I don't have access to the script.  Is there a way to use js/jQuery to submit an AJAX request, and then load the target page when it is finished processing?  Something like this is what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#myForm").submit(function () {
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.post("url/to/script.php", data, function (results) {
                // replace this entire document, url included, with the results
            });
            $("#spinner").hide().ajaxStart(function () {
                $(this).show();
            }).ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am open to alternative ideas as well.

[edit]

To (hopefully) clarify: I want the results to load in the background, and only navigate to them when they are done.  The behavior (with the exception of the spinner) should be no different to the end user than submitting the form without using javascript.

[edit 2]

I managed to convince the owner of the target script to put a spinner in place, so the question is now academic.

Comment: what you mean with "url included"? what returns the ajax? For replace entire documento do `$("body").html(results);`

Comment: I tried that, and get a blank screen.  I suspect that it has to do with what is in the <head> of the results.  I tried parsing the results into head and body, and then assigning them through jQuery, with the same net result (blank screen).

Comment: The AJAX is returned in the variable "results", as part of the success function ($.post() accepts the anonymous function as a shortcut to adding a success function to the AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly...you cannot replace the url with javascript. Can you not just window.location.href = "your-new-url.com" on success of the ajax?

If you can't do that you could post your resulting data from the ajax request to the new url and just have that page spit out your result.

Comment: Setting window.location.href = url causes the browser to load the target url, as a completely new request, which defeats the purpose. Adding the returned html to the url bar breaks the relative links (as does inserting the results into the search page).

Comment: @asgallant I am aware of what that does. I guess I don't really understand you correctly. If you could provide more information on what it is that you are trying to maybe I could help you further?